# how to paginate by scroll in android listView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a listView with an adapter.

I want to get from the servers the items and then I load an image to each item.

The server can return tens of items so I ask them from the client by pages of 10.

I don't want the user to choose a page or "next\back"

Just to add more items when needed.

I have thought to use a local collection and fill it with the next ten items.

My indicator is in Adapter::getView where position == 8.

The problem is that the function that fills the local collection from the server response is outside of the adapter.

How can I call this method and then refresh the adapter or invalidate it?

Would you use a different approach ?

Since I load images I need to compress them so I cannot use and ready-made endless-lists which are stored on git.

Comment: use PagedCursor: https://gist.github.com/pskink/b21c932f405740011144 the testing provider is here: https://gist.github.com/pskink/9ab862cdd0d6b0281ab4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not matter that function is where, you just need a few step.

1- define page number in adapter.

```
 int pageNumber;

 // getter and setter
```

2- define a method in getView for the time that:

```
if (position == list.size()-2 && list.size() < totalRecord)  // this make 8 , 18 , ...
    getMoreData();
```

total record is all record that you have in server side

then in getMore function call Parent method:

if is in activity:

```
  ((ActivityName)context).functionName();
```

if is in fragment class, one way is pass Fragment class to adapter, then call:

```
 fragment.functionName();
```

then in function on activity just increase value of `pageNumber` (adapter.setPageNumber(++adapter.getPageNumber()) and add data to list then call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();`

and last step, because It's might `getMoreData();` called more that once you can add one boolean value for checking that did that called or not like follow:

```
if (position == list.size()-2 && list.size() < totalRecord && isCanLoad())
```

in getMoreData() change that to `false` and after getting all data from activity/fragment class change that to `true` again.

Comment: thanks. how can I avoid multi calls to the same position in getView() ?

Comment: you must handle that with one boolean flag, I've use `canLoad` in this answer, in default is true, after calling method change that to false and after get data from server ( or anywhere else ) change back to true

Comment: but then it calls getView with the same position. and this will trigger the whole `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to add more items to a listView :

1. Add data items to the Collection which was used to create the adapter generally an ArrayList.
2. call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after all items are added.

Comment: Nope. calling notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter will ensure that the adapter refreshes its views.

Comment: but then it calls getView with the same position. and this will trigger the whole `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` again and again.

Comment: Why ? Can you post the code where you fetch new data and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`